# Xamarin ListView UI refresh leaves blank rows

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listView in xamarin that is binded to an Observable Collection. When I remove items it automatically displays on the UI as planned.

The Problem comes in, when I remove the very first item in the listview, then the 2nd row moves up into the first row, the second row becomes an empty row (no UI or data) and the rest of the rows stay the same. The view is fixed when I scroll away and then back again, but I want it to work on removal of the item.

I am using the RetainElement Caching strategy. Everything works with the recycleElement strategy, except I have to load hundreds of rows of data which causes heavy lag with RecycleElement.

What I have tried:

- Shrinking the size of the View before removing the cell
- Normal removing the item from the Observable collection
- Different Caching Strategies

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Full source code is available at https://github.com/staircase27/XamarinFormsAndroidListViewError/tree/master

The main pages .xaml file contains

Comment: Can you please explain why you added row Height as -1?